# accent in column name sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to query the sql server database through php and the field name has an accent and I get the following error.

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

the code is:

```
$sql='SELECT introductión FROM table;              
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);   
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt ) ) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Is `mysql` related?

Comment: `$sql='SELECT introductión FROM table;` you did forget a quote here if that is your actual code; we don't know that; you do. `$sql='SELECT introductión FROM table';` and make sure you use the right collation for it.

Comment: we also don't know if `table` is also the actual table name or not; you do.

Comment: Although a number of answers suggest the `introductión` column needs to be enclosed, that is not the case since it conforms to the regular identifier naming rules (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `[]` to delimit column (or table, or etc...) names.
In MySQL, you typically use the ` (the one on the ~ key).

Answer (score 1):

Try this: SELECT [introductión] FROM table;

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the column name in square brackets.

```
$sql='SELECT [introductión] FROM table';
```